# Get category from slug list

Tags: categories, query, sql, slug

I've a list of url's and I want to get the categories of each one. Whats the best way to achieve this?

Thanks.
Diego

Comment: you have the URL or the slug ? it's not the same information. from the slug you can have all datas with this function : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by

Comment: I have the URL in a CSV from my SEO partner.

Answer (score 0):

```
$category_slug_array = array('slug_1', 'slug_2', 'slug_2'); //array of category slugs

foreach($category_slug_array as $category_slug){
   $my_categories[] = get_term_by( 'slug', $category_slug, 'category'); //getting category object by slug
}

print_r($my_categories); //printing array of categories
```

Comment: Could you please edit your answer and add in an explanation on what this piece of code does, where to add it, and how it solves the original issue?